# Python: Low level apply rotation to an object

Tags: python

How to apply rotation directly to an object in Python (not BGE, not bpy.ops...)?

```
import bpy
import mathutils
from mathutils import*

obj = bpy.context.active_object
obj.rotation_euler = Vector([0, 0, 45])

#obj.apply_rotation
#Apply rotation like CTRL+A -> Rotation
```

Thanks!

I need a method for an object that's been already rotated like in my example code.

Comment: Does the python script you included function correctly or incorrectly?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger corrected the error, so now it works except for the "apply rotation" part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To apply transformation really low-level, you should probably set the object's matrix directly and avoid `bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()` entirely:

```
import bpy
from math import radians
from mathutils import Euler, Matrix

euler = Euler(map(radians, (0, 0, 45)), 'XYZ')

ob = bpy.context.object

loc, rot, scale = ob.matrix_world.decompose()

smat = Matrix()
for i in range(3):
    smat[i][i] = scale[i]

mat = Matrix.Translation(loc) * euler.to_matrix().to_4x4() * smat

ob.matrix_world = mat
```

Change the last line to `ob.matrix_local = ob.matrix_parent_inverse * mat` if you want to set a rotation of `0°, 0°, 45°` (as seen in Object tab) even if the object is parented.

The code might need further adjustments if drivers or modifiers are involved, non-uniform scaling in combination with parenting does not seems to work fine however.

Comment: Am I missing something - or does this not work in newer versions?  This code appears to rotate the object without applying the rotation as was requested.

Comment: @splic On blender 2.8+, change `mat = Matrix.Translation(loc) * euler.to_matrix().to_4x4() * smat` to `mat = Matrix.Translation(loc) @ euler.to_matrix().to_4x4() @ smat` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> executes this operator:

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply( rotation = True )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in bmesh with each vertex and then reset the object transformation:

```
rObj = bpy.context.object
vScale = mathutils.Vector(rObj.scale)
vLocation = mathutils.Vector(rObj.location)
rObj.scale = (1.0,1.0,1.0)
rObj.location = (0,0,0)
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(rObj.data)
for v in bm.verts:
  v.co = rObj.matrix_world * v.co
bm.to_mesh(rObj.data)
bm.free()
rObj.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)
rObj.scale = vScale
rObj.location = vLocation
```

Comment: Welcome to bse. The question does stipulate applying rotation. Can you add [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/116807/edit) to answer for this case?